# pass data from callback (aws dynamodb scan) to outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am retrieving the data from dynamodb with aws's dbclient.scan function. I need to use the output data to retrieve data from another table. I am trying to assign the output of first db scan into variable that is outside of dbclient.scan. The problem is that I get empty variable eventhough I assigned data from dbclient.scan callback function. What should I do? Anyway, I haven't used promise and asynchronous concept. The following is the code that I wrote.

```
var tmp = []
docClient.scan(params, (error, result) => {
     if(error) { .......} 
     else{ var tmp1 = result.Items[0].data
           tmp.push(tmp1)
     }
});
console.log(tmp)//empty list
```

What should I do?
Many thanks,
Sea

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how Javascript and callbacks work. Javascript will process the whole file from the top down instantly. So when you're doing the `console.log(tmp)` the DynamoDB scan above has not finished yet.

Try changing your code to the following to view the data from DynamoDB:

```
    var tmp = []
    docClient.scan(params, (error, result) => {
      if(error) { .......} 
      else {
        var tmp1 = result.Items[0].data
        tmp.push(tmp1)

        // now get item using results from scan   
        var params = {
          TableName: "mytable",
          Key: {
            KeyName: tmp1.KeyName
          }
        }
        docClient.get(params, (error, results) => {
          console.log(results)
        })

      }
    });
```

I would highly recommend taking a look at async/await ([Google results for tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20async%20await%20tutorial&oq=javascript%20async%2Fawait%20t&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j69i60l3j0l2.5871j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)). This will make your life so much easier when dealing with nested callbacks.

Comment: John, because I need to use the output as a key to query the data from another table. If so what should I do.

Comment: You will need to enter callback hell my friend. I'll update the answer to show how you would do that.

Comment: Thank for your help John. It work now. Many thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I found this is the easiest way to do this is like this:

```
let request = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'})
let params = {
    TableName: 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
    Key: {
        'YOUR_KEY': { S: 'STRING_VALUE_TO_MATCH' }
    }
}
let result = await request.getItem(params).promise().then((data) => {
    return data.Item 
})
// Now you can use result outside of the promise.
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Make sure this is inside an async function and it should work for you. This isn't for a "scan" but the concept should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

until someone shows me a sane way of doing this, with real life code examples, this approach will usually work fine:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let results;
await dynamodb.scan({
  TableName : 'your_table_name',
  Limit : 10
}, function(err, data) {
  results = data;
}.bind(this));

while (results === undefined) {
  await sleep(1000);
}
```